# Why won't excel instances not quit

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am trying to delete named ranges from a bunch of excel files.

Getting the following exception throws when the code is running:

"Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"

Tried everything thing I could think of but excel instances just won't quit!

Please see the code pasted below. Interop is no less than a horrible nightmare! :(

[image]

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace excel_delete_nr
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                String tp_folder = @"C:\tp";
                String[] tps = Directory.GetFiles(tp_folder);

                foreach (String m in tps)
                {

                   var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                   var xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
                   var xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(m);


                    var ranges = xlWorkbook.Names;
                    int leftoveritems = ranges.Count;


                    while (leftoveritems > 0)
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        try
                        {
                            while (i <= leftoveritems)
                            {
                                xlWorkbook.Names.Item(i).Delete();
                                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i + " deleted.");
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }

                        ranges = xlWorkbook.Names;
                        leftoveritems = ranges.Count;
                    }



                    xlWorkbook.Save();
                    xlWorkbook.Close();
                    xlWorkbooks.Close();
                    xlApp.Quit();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ranges);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are wanting to delete data from the Excel file, correct? What do you mean by `the excel file just won't quit`? Are you meaning it `continues to throw the exception` or that the `instance of Excel does not exit and remains open`?

Comment: The data gets deleted and the console application quits but excel remains open in the background.

Comment: Are you hitting any exceptions before the `xlApp.Quit();` ? Have you tried having your `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` *before* your `xlApp.Quit()` and `Close()`s?

Comment: Try adding a System.GC.Collect(): after the Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp); to force clean up of anything left in memory.  Normally .NET handles this on it's own, but ComInterop objects like to to hang around.

Comment: Yeah you need to release the com object on the Workbook and the workspace

Comment: Exceptions are hit upon before Quit. I have tried what you said I get "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used", excel still running in bkgrnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the below code. You must be really careful when working with Interop.
**But** if you have such simple task and if you know all your files will be the *new format* (understand Open XML) than I would use OpenXML solution where you don't need to use Excel at all and it significantly faster. Check it below

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Which solution to use?\n1  - for running Excel or \n2 - for using OpenXML");
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) return;

            String tp_folder = @"c:\tp\";
            String[] tps = Directory.GetFiles(tp_folder);

            if (result == "1")
            {
                DeleteNamesWithExcelApp(tps);
            }
            else if (result == "2")
            {
                var cls = new OpenXmlSolution();
                foreach (String m in tps)
                {
                    cls.RemoveNames(m);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void DeleteNamesWithExcelApp(String[] tps)
        {

            Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = null;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
            Excel.Names ranges = null;

            var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                foreach (String m in tps)
                {
                    xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
                    xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(m);
                    ranges = xlWorkbook.Names;
                    int leftoveritems = ranges.Count;

                    Excel.Name name = null;
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = leftoveritems; i >= 1; i--)
                        {
                            name = xlWorkbook.Names.Item(i);
                            name.Delete();
                            if (name != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(name);
                            name = null;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (name != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(name);
                    }
                    if (xlWorkbook != null)
                    {
                        xlWorkbook.Close(true);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
                        xlWorkbook = null;
                    }
                    if (xlWorkbooks != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ranges != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ranges);
                if (xlWorkbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
                if (xlWorkbooks != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
                if (xlApp != null)
                {
                    xlApp.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                    xlApp = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the OpenXML solution I'd prefer. I really don't know how it behaves with old xls files.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class OpenXmlSolution
    {
        public void RemoveNames(string fullPathToFile)
        {            
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fullPathToFile, true))
            {
                WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                var numOfNames = wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Count();
                if (numOfNames == 0) return;
                for (int i = numOfNames -1 ; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.ChildElements[i].Remove();
                }                
                wbPart.Workbook.Save();                
            }
        }
    }
}
```